# extract the datas from a array using php

Tags: php, arrays, submit

i searched previous sample questions but those are not helpful my question..
My task is i have several types of rooms in my hotel. when i select the rooms, after submit the form the room numbers and price details should be store into redirected page.

i use this command

here I modified my code like below

```
<?php while($row24 = mysql_fetch_array($result24)):;?>
                    <div class="item-gallery isotope-item bo-rad-10 hov-img-zoom triple">
                        <?php echo "<img src='images/$row24[pic]' alt='IMG-GALLERY'>"?>
                            <div class="overlay-item-gallery trans-0-4 flex-c-m">
                            <?php echo "<a class='btn-show-gallery flex-c-m fa fa-search' href='images/$row24[pic]' data-lightbox='gallery'></a>"?>&nbsp &nbsp
                            <?php echo "<label class='container1 txt17'>Select Room
                              <input type='checkbox' name = 'check_list[]' value='$row24[roomno] ,$row24[price]'>
                              <span class='checkmark'></span>
                            </label>"?>

                            </div>
                            <div class="line-item-mainmenu text-blo3 size21 flex-col-l-m">
                                <?php echo "<span class='txt20 m-b-3'>" .'Room No : ' 
                                    .$row24['roomno'].
                                "</span>"?>
                                <?php echo "<input type='text' class=' txt16 m-b-3'>".'Price  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp : '
                                    .$row24['price']."&nbsp &nbsp<i class='fa fa-rupee'></i>"."&nbsp &nbsp(One Night )" ?>
                            </div>  
                    </div>

                    <?php endwhile;?>
```

by using this code i get he results which i expect. but my problem is how to extract price from that array

Comment: The only loop in this code is the while.  So if you see multiple results, it means you got many results from the query that produced $result24.  Do a `var_dump($result24);` to see the full contents.  You might need to fix your query (which is absent from the question) or clean up your database table of duplicate entries.

Comment: no duplicate entries in my table sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When including object/array elements in strings, you need to wrap them with `{}` so they will be parsed properly.

For example

```
<?php echo "<img src='images/$row24[pic]' alt='IMG-GALLERY'>"?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo "<img src='images/{$row24[pic]}' alt='IMG-GALLERY'>"?>
```

Aside from that, it does not matter what room is selected, all these form fields (minus those unchecked input boxes) are going to be submitted and you'll have a tough time trying to parse the data out.

If, at the very least, assign `roomno` as an associative key for each of your fields, for example:

```
<input type='checkbox' name = 'check_list[]' value='{$row24[roomno]}'>
<input type='text' name='price[]' value='{$row24[roomno][price]}' />
```

That way, at least you can iterate through the `$_POST`, price field(s) based on the `roomno` key selection(s).